# Javascript Recursion thru children and display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to display a result based on nested children's value. I am using the recursion function for this. I am having trouble with how will I display it to HTML based on the example result below.
I am using React.js.

For now I am using console.log.
Here is my code: (Sample data are in the bottom)

```js
function recursion(data, label) {
  if (!data) {
    return;
  }
  for (let a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
    const item = data[a]
    if (!item.items) {
      const isLast = data.length - a === a
      console.log(`(${item.course_id}) ${ isLast ? '' : label} `)
    } else {
      if (label) console.log(label)
      recursion(item.items, item.type)
    }
  }
}

/*
Example result that I want to achieve is something like be: 

    (1894 $or 1501)
    $or
    (7068 $or 7120 or 7141) 
    $or 
 (997 $and 9001)
    $or
    (7256 $or 4534)
*/

//My sample data:

const data = [{
  "type": "$or",
  "items": [{
      "course_id": "1894"
    },
    {
      "course_id": "1501"
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [{
          "course_id": "7068"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7120"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7141"
        },
        {
          "type": "$and",
          "items": [{
              "course_id": "997"
            },
            {
              "course_id": "9001"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [{
          "course_id": "7256"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "4534"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

//start here
recursion(data)
```

Comment: display by console.log?

Comment: Nope, I want to display it in HTML as text.
I am just using console.log for debugging .

Comment: should there be an indent in front of 997 or is that intentional?

Comment: No indent needed. I will edit  it.

Comment: I updated my code and I almost got it but for now, I am displaying it in the console.log and there is still a minor issue in my result.  @Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puts all leaf nodes (nodes without children) in items into an array, then recurses into nodes.  Then joins them all together using the $type.

```js
const data = [{
  "type": "$or",
  "items": [
    {
      "course_id": "1894"
    },
    {
      "course_id": "1501"
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [
        {
          "course_id": "7068"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7120"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7141"
        },
        {
          "type": "$and",
          "items": [
            {
              "course_id": "997"
            },
            {
              "course_id": "9001"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [
        {
          "course_id": "7256"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "4534"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

/*
function recursion(data, label) {
  if (!data) { return; }
  for (let a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
    const item = data[a]
    if (!item.items){
      console.log(`${item.course_id} ${label} `)
    } else {
      console.log('')
      console.log(label || '')
      setParentLabel = item.type
      const child = recursion(item.items, setParentLabel)
    }
  }
}
*/
const recursion = (data, label) => {
  let nodes = [[]];
  const type = data.type;
  data.items.forEach( x => {
    const leafs = nodes[0];
    const isLeaf = !x.items;
    if ( isLeaf ) leafs.push( x.course_id );
    else nodes.push( recursion( x, x.type ) );
  });
  if ( nodes[0].length > 0 )
    nodes[0] = '('+nodes[0].join(` ${type} `)+')';
  else nodes = nodes.slice(1);
  let string = '';
  string = nodes.join(`\n${type}\n`);
  return string;
};
console.log(recursion({items: data}))
```

```js
const data = [{
  "type": "$or",
  "items": [
    {
      "course_id": "1894"
    },
    {
      "course_id": "1501"
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [
        {
          "course_id": "7068"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7120"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7141"
        },
        {
          "type": "$and",
          "items": [
            {
              "course_id": "997"
            },
            {
              "course_id": "9001"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [
        {
          "course_id": "7256"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "4534"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]

/*
Example result that I want to achieve is something like be: 

    (1894 $or 1501)
    $or
    (7068 $or 7120 or 7141) 
    $or 
 (997 $and 9001)
    $or
    (7256 $or 4534)
*/

function recursion(data, label) {
  if (!data) { return; }
  let nodes = [[]];
  let leafs = nodes[0];
  for (let a = 0; a < data.length; a++) {
    const item = data[a]
    if (!item.items){
      leafs.push(item.course_id)
    } else {
      setParentLabel = item.type
      const child = recursion(item.items, setParentLabel)
      nodes.push(child);
    }
  }
  if ( nodes[0].length > 0 )
    nodes[0] = '(' + nodes[0].join(` ${label} `) + ')';
  else nodes = nodes.slice(1);
  return nodes.filter(x=>!!x).join(`\n${label}\n`);
}

console.log(recursion(data))
```

Comment: I can also display this as HTML? I am using React.js.

Comment: Sure, I'm about to post a version that is more directly based on yours.  Basically instead of returning strings, you can return React components, and have the React component creating itself.

Comment: It would look something like `return <> { nodes.filter(x=>!!x).map(x=><RecursiveComponent items={x.items} label={x.type}></RecursiveComponent>) <>`

Comment: I'd recommend you do it yourself and figure it out since you appear to be learning React.  Will be a good practice exercise to get a basic feel for React's structure

Comment: Maybe create separate components for Leaf nodes, Child nodes, and List of Nodes, just to get a feeling for components, even though it's not really necessary.  Just my two cents.

Comment: You probably have an empty node in there being getting joined, like ["class1", "", "class2"].  Try to filter your returned nodes for blank or invalid nodes.  So in the example above check to make sure "course_id" has a valid value before adding it to the array, or filter it out later.

Comment: Also, in the code above I accumulate all the leaf nodes and join them before the children nodes.   Looking at that, it looks like that might not be your desired behavior?  You want them to always be listed in the order that they are listed in the array?

Comment: Copy , thanks. The display I want is what I want in the result example above, but I am having trouble to style it since when the item is push in the left, I can't push a HTML elements so it's pure string. Once I display it it is really ugly, no spacing.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const unSortedData = [{
  "type": "$or",
  "items": [{
      "course_id": "1894"
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [{
          "course_id": "7068"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7120"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7141"
        },
        {
          "type": "$and",
          "items": [{
              "course_id": "997"
            },
            {
              "course_id": "9001"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [{
          "course_id": "7256"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "4534"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "course_id": "1501"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "$or",
  "items": [{
      "course_id": "1894"
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [{
          "course_id": "7068"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7120"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "7141"
        },
        {
          "type": "$and",
          "items": [{
              "course_id": "997"
            },
            {
              "course_id": "9001"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "$or",
      "items": [{
          "course_id": "7256"
        },
        {
          "course_id": "4534"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "course_id": "1501"
    }
  ]
}]
 /**Inorder to split between two data I have used value.type if you want
    *something else then you can use your own delimiter(just replace 
    *value.type with your requirement). Also if you want to store the looped 
    *item, you can store it into an array rather than returning string value. 
    *Example instead of dataJoiner you an use
    *const arr = [];
    *Inside forEach loop. arr.push(loopItems(value.items, value.type));
    *and finally return arr. It's clearly upto you what you want to do with 
    *the recursed item
**/
function loopData(data) {
 let dataJoiner = '';
 data.forEach(value => {
  dataJoiner = `${dataJoiner}\n ${dataJoiner ? ' ' + value.type + ' '  : dataJoiner}\n ${loopItems(value.items, value.type)})`;   
 }); 
  console.log(dataJoiner);
  return dataJoiner;
};

 /** In this method items are sorted as per object type. Objects with only 
    *course_id are sorted and then Object with items are sorted. After that 
    *using     
    *reduce funtion it checks whether item has type and if it hasn't it     
    *accumulates by joining course_id with the given type. And whenever it     
    *detects type on the item it recursively calls loopItems whose result is     
    *accumulated into accumulator i.e. acc
**/
function loopItems(items, type) {
 if(items && items.length) {
 const sortedItems = items.sort((a, b) => Object.keys(a).length - Object.keys(b).length);
  return sortedItems.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
   if(item.type) {
       return `${acc})\n ${acc ? ' ' + type + ' '  : acc}\n ${loopItems(item.items, item.type)}`; 
   }
   const leftBracket = index === 0 ? '(' : '' 
   return `${leftBracket }${acc}${acc ? ' ' + type + ' '  : acc}${item.course_id}`;
  }, '');
 }
}

loopData(unSortedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursion(items, type = '') {
    let result = [];
    for (let item of items) {
        if (!item.items && !item.type) {
            result.push(item.course_id);
        } else {
            result.push(`(${recursion(item.items, item.type)})`);
        }
    }
    return result.join(` ${type} `);
}

//start here
console.log(recursion(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried it but there are some minor issues such as some parenthesis for closing every item.